# DoubleAnimation duration property in metro?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

This should work in WPF:

```
DoubleAnimation d = new DoubleAnimation();
d.From = box.Width;
d.To = 1000;
d.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) ;
```

However, in metro (windows 8), the last line is giving me the error:

> 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Intelisense also seems to think Duration needs no parameters.

Any ideas/work arounds? Is my installation broken?

Comment: No, your installation is not broken.

Comment: have you tried doing only `d.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);`

Comment: @codesparkle I did , but it says it can't convert it.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
d.Duration = new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

which is different than `Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration` and, as the OP reported, **doesn't work.** Does someone have a solution?

EDIT: have you tried setting TimeSpan directly?

```
d.Duration.TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

Check out the [MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.duration)

Comment: this feels like a bug, or at least an inconsistency, in the api.

Comment: But d.Duration is a Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration property - it doesn't work with the windows one....

Comment: I see. I don't actually have the Developer Tools to test this, sorry. Unmark it as an answer if it hasn't worked.

Comment: @user939165 I've edited my answer, does the second half work?

Comment: I get : Cannot modify the return value of 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Timeline.Duration' because it is not a variable.......Intelisense shows it next to a blue block-thingie instead of a pink one / property symbol , I'm not sure what that means -_-"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the static method FromTimeSpan on DurationHelper to create a duration.

```
d.Duration = DurationHelper.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```